ASP.NET & C# file upload - what is worng with my code
The file upload one line code is working, but when I integrate it in the web application, it doesn't work.
ASPX markup file:
<div class="form-group" style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">
    <label for="client_tax_photo_numInput1">صورة البطاقة الضريبية</label>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="client_tax_photo" />
</div>

C# code-behind file:
protected void Add_Ticket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addnewclient();
    addnewticket();
}

void addnewclient() 
{
    client_tax_photo.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../docs") + "//" + client_tax_photo.FileName);
}

void addnewticket() 
{
    // ...
}

I created a page to test the file upload to make sure it's not a permissions issue and it's working.
Would you please tell me what is wrong?

Probably need to map the root: Server.MapPath("~/docs")

You are right .. it wasnt pointing to the rooted path and the application dll wasnt updated .. many thanks

Where is your <form>? You need to have enctype="multipart/form-data"> in order to use <input type="file" />. Also, it's 2024...you should consider how you plan to migrate away from WebForms.

I would suggest using "~" that means start from root of the site.
Hence, this:
    void addnewclient()
    {
        string sFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/docs/") + client_tax_photo.FileName;

        client_tax_photo.SaveAs(sFile);
    }

So, above would resolve to:
  https://MySiteName.com/docs/"file name"


Using this code would allow anyone to upload anything to a web-accessible directory on an IIS web-server - so I could easily upload my own .aspx files with inline code that would give me a remote-shell from which I could totally pwn that server.

Uploading a file is uploading a file. If one wants to restrict extensions etc., then one is free to do as such.  I mean I fail to see any difference here then that since the dawn of the internet, and that of using a input with file type. So, yes, it goes without saying that to turn on a computer, it needs to be plugged in, and if one is allowing files to be uploaded, then appropriate security measures should be taken.  And any folder for uploading of files should have security set (not available from a URL), or at the very least in no such cases should a direct URL to such files be allowed.

what worked for me was client_tax_photo.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/docs") + "//" + client_tax_photo.FileName) many thanks for all the help
